# I am a new user here and had an answer deleted by a moderator. I would like to know why it was deleted so I can do better in the future

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I posted what I believed to be a good answer to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350509/make-a-very-simple-word-2010-addin-without-paid-versions-of-visual-studio). The question was about modifying the Ribbon in Word through an Add-In. My approach is to create a template Add-In with modified XML and supporting vba. The answer was deleted by a very experienced moderator.
**I would like to know what mistake I made in posting this.**

[image]

This site is different from other forums in which I've participated for the past 20 years and I want to be a good participant.

Note, I am a volunteer moderator on the Microsoft Answers forum. I am just trying to help some people in my spare time.

Comment: Because the answer was [in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731).

Comment: Imagine all the links broke, how useful is your answer at that point? We need an answer to work without needing to go elsewhere to read it. Links should be for additional reading or citations only.

Comment: Your answer doesn't need to contain *all* the details - details and download links being on another page is OK - but an answer should at least give a broad overview of the directions (an overview which is not simply a link collection).

Comment: There is also a potential self-promotion angle to consider. Have you had any other answers deleted, where you were linking to your own page? There are 5 links on that answer, and 3 point to your own website.

Comment: Also, look at the timeline of the answer.  You will see that it underwent 2 reviews (late answer, low quality).  I imagine this brought it to the attention of the moderator.

Comment: I notice you are linked to you own website in [seven non-deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A14133995+is%3Aanswer+url%3Aaddbalance.com&mixed=0), out of 23. Please make sure you are following the rules regarding [self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I am reading the references you've made.
I am in the habit of providing links where I know the links to be stable pages because those pages are likely to be updated with new information or ideas. I will try to modify this behavior.
My own site is where I have the most control over content. I make no money from the site and do not allow ads.

Comment: @toolic I do not know how to look at the timeline of the answer.
I now see that four of my answers have been deleted and I will be looking at those for a pattern.
Again, thank you all for your replies.

Comment: OK, I deleted one of those myself. In one, I was referring the asker to post the question on different forums and gave a link to a third-party tool. That question was deleted.

Comment: It's a pretty seductive question though. The question asks two questions at once (a no-no) and I have to be mighty forgiving on it to not call it out for asking for tool recommendations or offsite documentation in both of those questions (another no-no). You get what you ask for. I can't really think what other answers could be expected here than links to MSDN and such. Because what else? A fully working example of an add-in?

Comment: @yivi I've reviewed the page on self-promotion. My "product" is legal services and I am in no way promoting that here. Coding and Word questions are a hobby for me. In the future I will try to reproduce relevant parts of a page here in my answer. Again, thank you.

Comment: The timeline is the little clock icon on the left, under the downvote arrow: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63840405/timeline

Comment: Side note: Stack Overflow is different from forums mostly in that it's not a forum. It's a Q&A site.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon - To put it simply, if the content within the answer itself does not answer the question, then it likely isn't an appropriate answer for Stack Overflow.  You can quote and cite a reference link, but if it's your own website, you should make that crystal clear.  Furthermore, you really should be linking to your own website sparingly, this isn't free ad space (while you might not have ads, you sell a service on your website, if you want to advertise on Stack Overflow pay to for an ad).

Comment: Thank you all. I guess the one that was deleted is a response not suitable for this site. Explaining XML editing of the Office Ribbon would not be suitable for a Q&A site since really dealing with it requires a book. Greg's page makes a good start. I am learning.I will check the timelines on all of my responses.

Comment: What constitutes a "late answer?" If the purpose is to serve as a resource rather than just solve individual problems, is not a divergent but valid answer welcome at a late date? IMO, manually editing XML and vba is far simpler than coding a new ribbon solely through code. I did not understand the question to be asking for a code solution for a new ribbon.

Comment: An answer to a question, should answer the question it asked, does not matter if it’s submitted an hour after the question or 6 months.  Any question can be answered, provided what’s being submitted, actually answers the question.

Comment: In the timeline for that answer it was marked as a "late answer." I am curious as to the definition of that.